# como puedo pasar datos de una vista a controlador usando hiddenfor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-4

Este es mi vista y mando a traer el dato en el hiddenfor:

```
         @{ViewBag.Title = "mostraralumnoISmaestria";
        }


      @using (Html.BeginForm
       ("mostraralumnoISmaestria", "mostrarprofesor",
         FormMethod.Post,
            new { onsubmit = "return SubmitForm(this)" }))
           {
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)
           @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Nombre)
          }
```

Este es mi controlador

```
 public ActionResult GetDataISalumnomaestria
   (registroalumnocoordinador rg)
    {
        using (masterEntities db = new masterEntities())
        {
            //.OrderBy(x => x.alumno)               
            List<registroalumnocoordinador> empList =
           db.registroalumnocoordinador.Where
           (x => x.lineainvestigacion == 
            "Ingeniería de Software" 
           && x.grado=="maestria"
            )
           .ToList<registroalumnocoordinador>();
            return Json(new { data = empList },
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
           
        }
    }
```

Me gustaría traer el dato de la vista @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Nombre) al controlador GetDataISalumnomaestria en la parte de where alguien sabe como realizarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Veo que estas recibiendo tu modelo/entidad tal cual viene del formulario, por lo cual podría obtener el dato nombre de la siguiente manera

```
List<registroalumnocoordinador> empList =
           db.registroalumnocoordinador.Where
           (x => x.lineainvestigacion == 
            "Ingeniería de Software" 
           && x.grado=="maestria" 
           && x.Nombre == rg.Nombre )
           .ToList<registroalumnocoordinador>();
            return Json(new { data = empList },
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Espero te pueda servir